# remotion/reactjs not rendering images

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using a reactjs library called remotion to create video content. I've followed the documentation on how to import assets as well as use them but for some strange reason the images and css are still not working.as you can the documentation highlighted below instructs to create a public folder to add assets which will be used through the staticFile method.

remotion documentation

```
"to import assets in Remotion, create a public/ folder in your project and use staticFile() to import it."

my-video/
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/
│  ├─ logo.png
├─ src/
│  ├─ MyComp.tsx
│  ├─ Video.tsx
│  ├─ index.tsx
├─ package.json
--------
import { Img, staticFile } from "remotion";
 
export const MyComp: React.FC = () => {
  return <Img src={staticFile("logo.png")} />;
};
```

this is the my file which consist of my assets including the image and the component that my image is being processed in using the staticFile() method.

my remotion project

```
TheMachineAd/
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/
│  ├─ Marcus_Miller_The_Renaissance_Tour.jpg
├─ src/
│  ├─ TheMachine.tsx
│  ├─ Video.tsx
│  ├─ index.tsx
├─ package.json
```

artist image component

```
import React from "react";
import { Img, staticFile, useCurrentFrame, AbsoluteFill } from "remotion";

export const Artist_pic_1: React.FC = () => {
    const frame = useCurrentFrame();

    return (
        <AbsoluteFill>
           
            <Img style={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: "303px",
                right: "419px",
                width: "450px", 
                height: "auto"
            }}
            src={staticFile("Marcus_Miller_The_Renaissance_Tour")} />;

        </AbsoluteFill>
    );
};
```

main component rendering image

```
import { AbsoluteFill, Sequence, useCurrentFrame } from 'remotion';
import {useVideoConfig} from "remotion";
import { Text_box_1 } from './TheMachine/text-box-1';
import { Artist_pic_1 } from "./TheMachine/artist_pic_1";
import React from 'react';

export const TheMachine: React.FC = () => {
    const frame = useCurrentFrame();
    const {fps, durationInFrames, width, height} = useVideoConfig();

    return (
        <AbsoluteFill style={{backgroundColor: 'aqua'}}>
            <AbsoluteFill>
                <div
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        textAlign: "center",
                        fontSize: "7em",
                        color: "white",
                        }}
                >
                    The current frame is {frame}.
                    This {width}px x {height}px video is {durationInFrames / fps} seconds long.
                </div>
            </AbsoluteFill>
            <AbsoluteFill>
                <Sequence from={20}>
                     <Text_box_1 /> 
                </Sequence>
            </AbsoluteFill>
                <Sequence from={50}>
                    <Artist_pic_1 />
                </Sequence>
        </AbsoluteFill>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put an image into the public/ folder and use staticFile() to reference it.**

```
import { AbsoluteFill, Img, staticFile } from "remotion";
 
export const MyComp: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <AbsoluteFill>
      <Img src={staticFile("hi.png")} />
    </AbsoluteFill>
  );
};
```

**You can also load a remote image:**

```
import { AbsoluteFill, Img } from "remotion";
 
export const MyComp: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <AbsoluteFill>
      <Img src={"https://idkblogs.com/images/logo/logo1_250x150.png"} />
    </AbsoluteFill>
  );
};
```